# Angular Material 6.0.1 : how to expand any node in angular mat-tree?

Tags: tree, angular-material, angular6

expand/collapse all the nodes in mat-tree is working fine. but I don't understand how to expand particular node in mat-tree?

Please provide any reference or solution for this.

Comment: [plese consult help section on how to formulate your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) You usually get as much help as you put effort into question formulation.

Comment: Could you show what you've tried so far ?

Comment: I have tried few things and got to know that treeControl of mat-tree consists nodes which i want to expand.

var nodes = this.treeControlTarget.dataNodes;
 let referenceToNode = nodes.find(d => condition to find node)
this.treeControlTarget.expand(referenceToNode);

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

**I know the material versions may be different between this stackblitz and version 6.0.1... but the concept should still apply to version 6.0.1**

Please reference the `ngAfterViewInit()` on this stackblitz example.

- You need to call `expand()` on your treeControl for each node you want to expand and pass the node.

This stackblitz pre-selects the `Fruits` category and expands the `Groceries` tree and the `Fruits` tree on init.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j2nf2r?embed=1&file=app/tree-checklist-example.html

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.treeControl.dataNodes.length; i++) {
      if (this.treeControl.dataNodes[i].item == 'Fruits') {
        this.todoItemSelectionToggle(this.treeControl.dataNodes[i]);
        this.treeControl.expand(this.treeControl.dataNodes[i])
      }
      if (this.treeControl.dataNodes[i].item == 'Groceries') {
        this.treeControl.expand(this.treeControl.dataNodes[i])
      }
    }
  }
```